# Decomposition - Diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

I have an apparently naïve problem namely below

\begin{equation}
M = \begin{bmatrix}
m_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & m_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & m_2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & m_2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m_3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & m_3
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

I suspect I may write it somehow in the form dependent of

\begin{equation}
M' = \begin{bmatrix}
m_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & m_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & m_3 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

But I do not grasp the way. Would you help on this task? I am looking forward for it.

Beste regards,
Senzu

Comment: This only works if we permute rows and colums. But then this is no longer the same matrix. The matrix $M$ is of block form with blocks $m_iI_2$ for $i=1,2,3$.

Comment: No problem. My goal is to write it in a manner it only contains elemental matrices.

Comment: This seems like a product of Kronecker product of matrices… But I might not be helpful at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with tensor product,

$$M = M' \otimes I_2$$

We also have

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & & & \\ & O_2 & I_2 & \\ & I_2 & O_2 & \\ & & & 1 \end{bmatrix}M\begin{bmatrix}1 & & & \\ & O_2 & I_2 & \\ & I_2 & O_2 & \\ & & & 1 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} M' & O_3 \\ O_3 & M'\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I thank you, sir!

Comment: An even more appreciated way to compute it would be to have only one M' on the identity in such a way it is symmetric.

Comment: If it is not much, is it possible?

Comment: hmmm... not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: :'( Sad Senzu is sad